# Buzz in the G string

Tags: strings, classical-guitar, buzz

Three months ago, I decided to learn how to play guitar, and I bought a Gomez 001, http://tinyurl.com/mfbmdta.

Since I didn't know anything about guitars, I thought it was pretty good. And my teacher said that it was ok for a beginner.

But last Monday, I started noticing a buzz every time I strummed a chord. I then realized that there was actually something wrong with the G string.

I went to the store, the guy there checked the guitar, said that there was actually something strange and decided to give me another guitar.

Turns all that all guitars of that model he had in the store had the same problem and other guitars had different strings with the same problem.

So I returned that guitar, and bought a better one, a Artesano Sonata RS, http://www.artesanoguitars.com/sonata/sonata.html.

I bought it on Saturday and when I got home and started on my exercises again, I started hearing the same buzz again on the G string.

When I strum the string with my thumb, to check if it's in tune, it seems that the string doesn't vibrate like the other strings, it seems a bit wobbly, like it is vibrating unevenly.

And although my guitar tuner app says that the string is in tune, I found the sound from this string a bit strange.

Here's a little video,

So, am I a lousy guitar player or am I just having bad luck with the G string??

Cheers
Rui Martins

Comment: when you pick a fretted note on the string does it keep buzzing, or is the problem on open position only?

Comment: The string buzzes when I strum a little harder, whether open or fretted. I am training flamenco strum patterns.

Comment: Check the excess strings that are both sides of each string. They tend to resonate with some sounds when not fixed to somewhere.

Comment: The temptaition to suggest that you can get a cream to cure "G-string buzz" has just overwhelmed me. Fortunately I posted an answer as well

Comment: +1 comment. It's all getting too serious. I thought musos had senses of humour. Wrong again...

Comment: You may have a loosely fitting tuning machine. Try playing that string while holding the machine. Also inspect the tying block for loose pieces. Also your strings look strange, as if they are all of the same thickness (though this might be just a video quality thing). Are you sure you have put a G string and not some other string there? :)

Comment: The thing is,n.m., the guitar is brand new. Those are the strings that came with it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my classical guitar: it buzzed whenever a G was played (open G-string or A and E-string when playing G as well). Turned out that this was caused by the end of the three metal strings (D, A, E) touched the back of the bridge! I pulled these ends away from the back of the bridge and the buzz disappeared. See photo:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems odd- I can see why you'd be confused.

Logically, the common element making the G string buzz if yourself, as you've now tried 3 x guitars !

However I'm sure you've tried checking the string open & on the frets on all guitars.

I'd suggest this :

- Try playing just that string, open, and on all frets, to see how hard you have to oluck it before it buzzes.
- Try the same thing on the D string. Does it buzz ? Is it a similar amount ?

If it's behaving significantly differently, maybe there's a problem with this guitar also, although that would be the 3rd guitar and quite unlikely.

Another possibility is that the G string is generally one of the looser strings. That is: It doens't need to be all that tight to get to a G, so so you have the guitar tuned to concert pitch? If it's tune lower, it might be that the G string being one of the loosest is showing up that all the strings are generally a bit loose (tuned low). The thick E string may be susceptible too (depends on string gauge really)

Looser strings tent to buzz a bit more as they are able to flap about more while vibrating.

One possible cure might be to try thicker strings.

Another possibility is that it's not related to "fret buzz" but something else caught on the string. I have had a strange buzz which was a result of a frayed bit of string being caught up in an adjacent string (effectively a bit of muck left after re-stringing), so best check the string from end to end for any anomaly like something caught on it or perhaps a kink/slice in the string.

Finally: It *could* be your guitar playing. Are you catching the G string on an adjacent finger ? Or not fretting it properly ? If the G string sounds ok as you play it individually but not good when you play a chord, maybe you need to look at your fingering technique.

However it seems if you're trying your 3rd guitar, I daresay you've already considered this.

Comment: Like i said, the guy at the store tried all the guitars of Gomez 001 model he had and they all had the same problem. This is my second guitar and the first one actually had a problem. This happens when I strum harder because I'm training flamenco now. And I can see the G string wobble and buzz when I strum it hard. And it does seem like the string is loser than the other ones.

Comment: The string does not buzz When I pluck it, open or fretted, but is does wobble. It doesn't seem to vibrate evenly in comparison to the others. I've also been practicing scales and all the strings seem ok, but when I start strumming flamenco style, I can clearly hear the G string buzzing.

Comment: Maybe it's the gauge of the string if that particular one is wobbly... or the flamenco style shows up a weakness inthe guitar?

Comment: "or the flamenco style shows up a weakness inthe guitar?". I'm quite inclined to this.

Answer (score 0):

The G string may sound a bit flat but that's actually how it is voiced on your production model guitar. The only advice I could give someone looking for a production model guitar is to spend some time playing each model you find until you find the "one" that sounds "right" for you. Kremona makes really good affordable guitars. The Cordoba C5 is a high quality guitar that is very affordable. Buzzing is typically a free or bracing problem. Stay away from guitars that buzz with the exception of flamenco models. Their action is lower to accommodate the style so there will be some buzz. Stay away from classical guitars that don't feature a relief (slight concave) in the neck. Perticularly the Ibanez GA models. They all have flat necks and buzz. The pickup is outstanding however.